# Detecting addon uninstall event on FF4

Tags: firefox-addon

How can I detect when user has uninstall my addon on FF4 (for cleanup process)?
While it's working well on FF3, it does not work on FF4 beta...

I've tried this code sample: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager/Code_Samples

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Do you know of addon that support FF4 and has this event listener?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The sample code was slightly wrong and has been corrected.  [The diff can be seen here](https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=en/Addons/Add-on_Manager/Code_Samples&action=diff&revision=10&diff=11).